# how can I start Wiznote without GUI

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal, i3-wm

I'm new here but not really novice by Ubuntu. Now I have a little problem with Wiznote (its a cloud notepad):

I can start it from GUI (Unity) by click on the icon. But now I use an other WM (i3) and there are no icons.
startmenue is text only, so i cannot find how to start it now.

the `# find / -name wiznote` give me only some folders with sql-files and configurations but not an binary

So how can I start this program from the terminal?

some information you could need:
thinkpad t400
ubuntu 14.04
i3-wm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command to see all the files of an installed package:

```
dpkg -L wiznote
```

Then search the executable, eg. in `/usr/bin`

```
/usr/bin/WizNote
```